# Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs see files when IsFolderPicker = true;

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-api-code-pack

like the title says, is it possible (have been searching can't find any where this info) to see the files when the `IsForderPicker = true` ?

```
var dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
dlg.Title = "Select the directory";
dlg.IsFolderPicker = true;
```

have this code but wanted to see also the files not just Folders.

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142109/how-can-i-make-commonopenfiledialog-select-folders-only-but-still-show-files

Comment: Thanks, didn't seen that :/